# Jackson: Cannot deserialize instance of object out of START_ARRAY

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm getting this error when attempting to parse some JSON previously generated with Jackson. I generate the JSON like so

```
String ret = "";
ret = mapper.writeValueAsString(message.getPayload());
message.setPayload(ret);
```

Where message.getPayload() is a HashMap, in this instance containing two strings and a List of various objects. This creates the following malformed JSON

```
{
  "user" : "john d example",
  "items" : [ {
    "val" : 99.5,
    "id" : "phone",
    "qty" : 1
  }, {
    "val" : 15.5,
    "id" : "wine",
    "qty" : 4
  } ],
  "address" : "123 example street"
}
```

Which throws an exception when examined thusly

```
Map<String, Object> ret = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String s = (String)message.getPayload();
ret = mapper.readValue(s, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
```

How should I properly write this Map to JSON?

Comment: getPayload returns a HashMap but setPayload accepts a String? It's weird.

Comment: Well the payload is an Object type, I should say that in this instance getPayload returns a HashMap and then letter on the data is encoded as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TypeReference<Map<String, String>>` should be `TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>`. Jackson is attempting to parse the values as Strings rather than Lists because that is what it expects based on the TypeReference you passed in.